# How to disconnect VSCode completely from accessing the internet?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've disabled Telemtry and Crash updater from my VSCode settings. Still VSCode makes requests to the internet. I think It does that to query extension results and downloading, update the VSCode software, fetch the internet images in my markdown etc.

Consider I just installed VSCode, setup extensions which I want and then I'll choose to manually update VSCode from now on.

In windows defender "Allow an app through Firewall", I don't see VSCode there so that I can disable internet to VSCode.

I don't want any new extensions or updates, no fetching images from internet etc. Is there a way I can disconnect VSCode completely from accessing the internet?

Answer (score 0):

Go To File --> Preferences --> Settings. 
Type in the search bar "Update".

And disable what you need.They have a setting for everything. For example:

Extensions: Auto Check Updates --> Uncheck

Update: Enable Windows Background Update --> Uncheck.

Please See Attached Photo.

[image]